# Basemap cannot set aspect on 3D axis

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, aspect

I am using Basemap with a 3D graph to display ray paths. I would like to implement one of basemap's topo, shaded relief or bluemarble layers but I am running into the same issue over and over again:

```
NotImplementedError: It is not currently possible to manually set the aspect on 3D axes
```

I have already implemented fixed_aspect=False into calling the basemap
and have also tried ax.set_aspect('equal') which gives me the same error

I am using matplotlib ==2.2.3

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

from io import StringIO
import re

f = open("best-working4D.ray_paths", 'r') #125 waves - 125 "lines"
data = f.read()

lines = data.split('\n        ')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

extent = [300, 360, 50, 75]
bm = Basemap(llcrnrlon=extent[0], llcrnrlat=extent[2],
             urcrnrlon=extent[1], urcrnrlat=extent[3], resolution='l', fix_aspect= False)

bm.bluemarble()


for i in range(1, 119):
    wave = lines[i]
    j = wave.split('\n')
    k = []
    for i in j:
        k.append(i.split())
    
        x=[]
        y=[]
        z=[]
        n= 0
    for m in k[1:]:
        x.append(m[0])
        y.append(m[1])
        z.append(m[2])
    x= np.array(x).astype('float32')
    y= np.array(y).astype('float32')
    z= np.array(z).astype('float32')
    ax.plot3D(x,y,z, color='red')

##Plotting Tropopause
T_hi = 20
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(300,360), range(50,75))
zz = yy*0 + T_hi


ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, alpha=0.15)



ax.set_xlabel("Latitude [deg]")
ax.set_ylabel("Longitude [deg]")
ax.set_zlabel("Altitude [km]")

ax.add_collection3d(bm.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))

plt.show()
```

The basemap IS working for the bm.drawcoastlines just nothing else.

[IMAGELINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxnYI.png)
I would greatly appreciate any ideas!